# How to save a list of Custom Objects (contains drawable) in android?

Tags: android, mysql, json, list, save

I've developed a sidebar app, and the approach I've used now is to get all the Applications and let the user select his fav apps. Now I save the packageNames of these selected apps as Set in sharedPreferences and everytime the sidebar is triggered, a list of all installed apps are retrieved and then by checking the packageNames in the set saved I make a list of selected apps and show them. and it also has custom Icon pack integration so I have created custom object that stores the ResolveInfo, label and icon of each app and a list of these objects is passed to the adapter.

Now I wanted to implement shortcut feature as well. So for this the approach I was thinking of using was to save the list of custom objects directly and retrieve them without having to go through the trouble of getting a list everytime from the all apps list and also if its a custom shortcut I would have to save it somewhere and retrieve directly as it cant be retrieved from my previous approach.

The custom object looks like this:

```
public class MyAppInfo {

    public ResolveInfo info;

    public String label;

    public Drawable icon;

    public MyAppInfo() {
    }

    public MyAppInfo(ResolveInfo info, String label, Drawable icon) {
        this.info = info;
        this.label = label;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

I've looked into methods of saving list of custom objects and I've found that I can do this by using JSON, Flat files and MySQL Database.

I've tried JSON Array. But it just got stuck at saving the list and later it showed out of memory and other times, the app just crashed. I even tried to save it a file but it doesn't seem to working for me as the data is always null when I try to retrieve it. I haven't tried the SQL method as I don't know how to save Drawable in SQL.

Can someone please help me with this? What would be the best approach to save data in my case?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's the other apps icons that you're refering to, with the drawables.

If so, you should definately not use a JSON array or flat files. You should be using a database. And just FYI, MySQL is not available on Android, we use SQLite.

You should save all the regular data in the database as just strings, ints, booleans, etc, and then save the drawables as BLOBS (basically raw image data).

There are lots of guides/stackoverflow posts out there to help with the implementation of both the actual database, and storing drawables as BLOBS.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! And I'm sorry, I've never used SQL so don't really know about that's why I thought it was MySQL. Anyways I'll give your method a try. and the drawables are used because I use icon packs in the app and user can store icons on per app basis. I'll look around in stackoverflow for good guides but if you know of any guides, a link would be helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much! SQLite is awesome. The performance is significantly better than before.